# Why is linear relationship one of the assumptions needed for using Pearson correlation?

Tags: correlation, terminology

Isn't the whole point of using the Pearson correlation to test the strenght (and direction) of a potential linear relationship between two variables? Am I misunderstanding what *assumption* means?

Comment: An exact quote and context will be helpful.

Comment: I'm simply looking at the list of assumptions online such as "The assumptions for Pearson correlation coefficient are as follows: level of measurement, related pairs, absence of outliers, normality of variables, linearity, and homoscedasticity."

Comment: You can calculate Pearson correlation with all kinds of violations of those assumptions. What is the particular context?

Comment: There is no context, the question is general. Whereas other assumptions are important for getting a reliable result, the assumption of linearity seems superfluous to me as it is the very thing we are testing/quantifying using this method. It is like using Spearman correlation on a dataset we assume to be monotonic. Why jump the gun? The Spearman coefficient will tell me if the relationship is monotonic or not.

Comment: Okay, then you don’t need to check linearity before calculating the Pearson correlation. As for why you’re reading that you do...there’s some (perhaps implicit) context in what you’re reading.

Comment: Pearson, Spearman, Hoeffding's D, Kendall's tau, etc., all express patterns of linearity and/or montonicity. That hardly begins to capture the available metrics for other dependence patterns. For instance, Szekely's *distance correlation* is an unrestricted measure of both linear and nonlinear dependence. Zero correlation suggests independence, higher values suggest stronger association but it says nothing about the shape or sign of the dependence. *Mutual information* is a measure of the amount of information one variable reveals about another with 0 indicating independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is from the domain of logic, not statistics. Assumptions set the conditions under which the test/statistic is useful.

Suppose the relationship is nonlinear, then what is the meaning of "strength of linear relationship"? It's undefined. You could try Spearman or Kendall correlation for monotonic relationships that are nonlinear.

Comment: If the Pearson coefficient tells me that the strength of linear relationship is low, I will conclude that the data indicates a weak linearly relationship. Why would I assume the thing I am testing? On the other hand, I understand why I need to assume, for example, absence of outliers -- if I have outliers, Pearson will give me a misleading result; overestimating or underestimating linearity.

Comment: The way I understand your answer is that it makes no sense to quantify linearity of a dataset we do not think is fundamentally linear; e.g. if we think the underlying relationship is quadratic, it would not make sense to quantify linearity. But what if I don't assume any underyling relationship? Wouldn't it be valid to use Pearson correlation to check if linear relationship is a sensible relationship to assume for some dataset?

Comment: imagine, your data is $y=x^2+\varepsilon$, then what is "the strength of linear relationship between x and y? there's no linear term at all.

Comment: Can't I apply Pearson coefficient to decide _whether_ I believe _there is_ a linear term? This is slightly different from assuming that the linear term exists and then using Pearson coefficient to quantify the relevance of that linear term. The assumptions I make prior to using the method don't change due to the result of the method -- I will keep assuming the data is normal and had no outliers even if the Pearson coefficient is near zero. If I assume linearity, I will keep assumming it but will simply say it is weak.

Comment: Pearson test as a linearity test? Maybe.

Comment: If we calculate the p-value for the Pearson correlation coefficient, aren't we essentially testing linearity?

Comment: @waterlemon, no, not directly, especially if you take into account possibility of confounding. there may not be any relationship at all but due to a presence of other variables correlation would seem to be present